# TensorFlow FailedPreconditionError: iterator has not been initialized

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to display the values of tensors.

Here is my code:

```
#some code here
data = [data_tensor for data_tensor in data_dict.items()]
for i in data:
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print (sess.run(i[1]))
        print('_'*100)
```

However, I got the error:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): 
GetNext() failed because the iterator has not been initialized. 
Ensure that you have run the initializer operation for this iterator 
before getting the next element.
```

How to solve the problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try creating the session first, then setting data and looping through it. There is no need to create a new session in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Post the whole code snippet in which you call the GetNext() function. You seem to be missing something like `sess.run(iterator.initializer)` for your dataset iterator.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have a dataset iterator that has not been initialized. A dataset iterator is not a variable, hence does not get initialized with `tf.global_variables_intializer()`.

You have to initialize it explicitly by calling `sess.run(iterator.initializer)` on whatever dataset iterator you created (e.g. with `iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()`.

---

Additionally, note that each dataset iteration (running the `GetNext` node) yields a *complete element* of the dataset, even if you only care about a subset of the element. If `data_dict` is the output of an iteration (created with `data_dict = iterator.get_next()`), doing `print(sess.run(i[1]))`, while only giving you one of the k,v pairs in the dictionary, actually yields the whole `data_dict`. I expect that this pipeline would not give you the output you expect unless you reinitialize the iterator within the for loop.

To make what I'm saying more concrete, if you had a dataset created as follows, you would expect the following iteration outputs:

```
## dataset: [{'a':0, 'b':10}, {'a':1, 'b':11}, {'a':2, 'b':12}, ...]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10).map(lambda x: {'a': x, 'b': x + 10})
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_elem = iterator.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    print(sess.run(next_elem['a']))  # 0
    print(sess.run(next_elem['a']))  # 1
    print(sess.run(next_elem['b']))  # 12
```

Comment: I received the error `AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute 'make_initializableiterator'`.

Comment: Sorry, typo: s/make_initializableiterator/make_initializable_iterator

Answer (score 0):

Have you used any iterators in your previous code? If so, initialize them too.

Eg. `sess.run(validation_iterator.initializer)`